# CSS padding-top in IE7 working a little too well

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I have a navigation with a `padding-top: 148px;` in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, IE 9 & 8 its looks perfect, but in IE 7 its gives it too much, you can see an example of this at http://willruppelglass.com/index.php why is it doing this and how do I fix it?

Here is the CSS

```
.headerNav{
    color:#000;
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 1280px;
    padding-top: 148px;
}
```

Any help would appreciated, thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use below structure and adjust the padding of the `<div class="headerNav"></div>` because the upper elements have `float:left` property and you are using padding-top:148px; in IE7 the padding is applying inside the headerNav itself in comparison of other browsers.

In other browsers the padding is applying from the top of view port.

```
 <div class="headerText"></div>

   <div style="clear:both"></div> <!--this will clear the floating property for below elements and make the space and adjust all the elements below this div -->

<div class="headerNav"></div>
```

In below image (IE7) you can see the padding-top:148; is applying with in the div not from the top of the body.

[image]

See the padding-top:148px applying from the top of the body/viewport. in below image (Firefox)

[image]

Comment: see the actual problem you are facing here in screen shots. I tried padding-top:48px; it is giving output as required in IE7. You can use conditional comments and write separate css for IE7.

Comment: conditional comments? I have never heard of this, do you have an example or tutorial?

Comment: See the link and try for separate browsers - http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Comment: I tried `<!--[if IE 7]>

.headerNav{
    color:#000;
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 1280px;
    padding-top: 48px;
}

<![endif]-->` and it didnt work :(